# MongoDB connection

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to make a mongodb connection using PHP. The php script is called by ajax. here goes the code to create client:

```
        $host = 'localhost';
        $port = '27017';
        $url = "mongodb://$host:$port";
        $client = new Mongo("$url");
```

and further processing using this client.But the code doesn't seem to work. On dumping the client using var_dump the following output comes

```
object(Mongo)#1 (4) {
  ["connected"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["status"]=>
  NULL
  ["server":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["persistent":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```